# RDLC local report trying to render before loading datasource

Tags: vb.net, reporting, rdlc, localreport

I have created a local report that contains a few sub reports. I am trying to load the report straight to pdf based off the click of a button.

I have tried showing the report with report viewer and it shows up fine, but when I try to render directly to pdf I get an error about data source. When I debug the code I notice that my subprocessing function does run until after the button call function finishes and throws the error.

```
Dim reportParam As New ReportParameter("appId", appid)
    Dim reportParam2 As New ReportParameter("appDate", appDate)
    Dim reportParam3 As New ReportParameter("auditDate", Now)
    Dim reportArray As New ReportParameterCollection
    reportArray.Add(reportParam)
    reportArray.Add(reportParam2)
    reportArray.Add(reportParam3)
    AddHandler ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf    SetSubDataSource
     ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportArray)
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters("appID").DefaultValue = appid
    ObjectDataSource1.SelectParameters("appDate").DefaultValue = appDate
    ObjectDataSource1.DataBind()
    Dim warnings As Warning() = Nothing
    Dim streamids As String() = Nothing
    Dim mimeType As String = Nothing
    Dim encoding As String = Nothing
    Dim extension As String = Nothing
    Try
        ReportViewer1.DataBind()
        ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh()

        Dim byteViewer As Byte()
        byteViewer = ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Render("PDF", Nothing, mimeType, encoding, extension, streamids, warnings)
        Response.Buffer = True
        'Response.Clear()

        Response.ContentType = mimeType
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=test.pdf")
        Response.BinaryWrite(byteViewer)
        Response.OutputStream.Write(byteViewer, 0, byteViewer.Length)
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()
```

Thanks for your advice in advance, I just trying to figure out how to get the report to load data sources before it renders and not after this function is complete.